# Parsing a MultiLevel XML in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I need to parse an XML with multi-level multiple elements.

A sample XML:

```
<Studies>
    <Study ID="1">
        <Site Id="1">
            <Participant ID="111"/>
            <Participant ID="222"/>
        </Site>
        <Site Id="2">
            <Participant ID="333"/>
            <Participant ID="444"/>
        </Site>
    </Study>
    <Study ID="2">
        <Site Id="3">
            <Participant ID="555"/>
            <Participant ID="666"/>
        </Site>
        <Site Id="4">
            <Participant ID="777"/>
            <Participant ID="888"/>
        </Site>
    </Study>
</Studies>
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT
    StudyID = XC.value('@ID', 'int'),
    SiteId = XC2.value('@Id', 'int'),
    ParticipantId =  XC3.value('@ID', 'int')
FROM 
    @Xml.nodes('//Study') AS XT(XC)
CROSS APPLY
    xc.nodes('Site') AS XT2(XC2)
CROSS APPLY
    xc.nodes('Participant') AS XT3(XC3)
```

This returns no data. If I change

```
xc.nodes('Participant') AS XT3(XC3)
```

to

```
xc.nodes('//Participant') AS XT3(XC3)
```

it returns 32 rows.

I am expecting 8 rows though. Any pointers?

Comment: You need `CROSS APPLY xc2.nodes('Participant') AS XT3(XC3)`  (see `xc2` instead of `xc` !)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    StudyID = XC.value('../../@ID', 'int'),
    SiteId = XC.value('../@Id', 'int'),
    ParticipantId =  XC.value('@ID', 'int')
FROM 
    @Xml.nodes('//Studies/Study/Site/Participant') AS XT(XC)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try following [SQL XML query](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/xml-in-sql-server-hierarchy-levels-cross-apply.aspx) . You can also refer to sample tutorial

```
declare @xml xml = '
<Studies>
    <Study ID="1">
        <Site Id="1">
            <Participant ID="111"/>
            <Participant ID="222"/>
        </Site>
        <Site Id="2">
            <Participant ID="333"/>
            <Participant ID="444"/>
        </Site>
    </Study>
    <Study ID="2">
        <Site Id="3">
            <Participant ID="555"/>
            <Participant ID="666"/>
        </Site>
        <Site Id="4">
            <Participant ID="777"/>
            <Participant ID="888"/>
        </Site>
    </Study>
</Studies>'


select
    Study.value('@ID','int') as Study,
    Site.value('@Id','int') as Site,
    Participant.value('@ID','int') as Participant
from 
    @xml.nodes('/Studies/Study') as StudiesTbl(Study)
cross apply 
    StudiesTbl.Study.nodes('Site') as StudyTbl(Site) 
cross apply 
    StudyTbl.Site.nodes('Participant') as SiteTbl(Participant)
```